# IOS 8 auto height cell works but when i scroll up it jumps

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, custom-cell

I designed a swift project that basically list items in a tableview.  i take new data from server and add them end of the table. Until this point, everything works correctly, but when scroll up, it is **jump**. I use these two function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension   
}
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}
```

My custom cell class is basic :

```
class StatusTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var statusBodyLabel: TTTAttributedLabel!

@IBOutlet weak var statusCreateTimeLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    statusBodyLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue

}


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

}

I cant find any solution about it. This takes my three days.
Help me to solve jump  scrolling.

Thanks,

Comment: you can directly return 80 in heightforrowatindexpath

Comment: How good is the estimate of 80? What's the average height of the cells?

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal that would defeat the purpose of Autolayout.

Comment: @MaheshAgrawal cells content size differs.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch 80 is good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem! There are two steps i did.
Firstly, i calculate my custom cell's row height myself like this function

```
func heightForView(text:String, #font:UIFont, #width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()

    return label.frame.height
```

}

So my **heightForRowAtIndexPath** function appears like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return heightForView(.....)
}
```

And i **remove this function**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
}
```

To sum up, i calculate row height myself, instead of using **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** . Then i remove **heightForRowAtIndexPath** .

That's all. I hope it helps you guys.